# How can I close the sympy plotting window? (python)

Tags: python, plot, window, sympy, terminate

My code is as below.

```
....(omission)...
sympy.plot(func, (x,-2,20))
```

Then the plot window successfully pops up but it doesn't close(doesn't terminate).
Is there a function similar to plt.close() in sympy plot methods?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's not fully implemented. Assuming that you are running your code from a Python or IPython console, to achieve your objective we need to modify a few methods.

```py
from sympy import *
var("x")
from sympy.plotting.plot import Plot, MatplotlibBackend

def show(self):
    self.process_series()
    self.fig.tight_layout()
    self.plt.show(block=False)
MatplotlibBackend.show = show

def close(self):
    self._backend.close()
Plot.close = close

p = plot(sin(x))
# at this point the matplotlib window is "detached" from the console.
# you can execute other commands. Finally, when you are ready to close
# the figure, run this:
p.close()
```